# Nothing but to be or nothing but be?

Tags: verbs, conjunctions, infinitives, bare-infinitives

I am a bit confused whether bare Infinitive is used after 'but' or not.

**Which one is correct?**

**We want nothing but to be free.**

**We want nothing but be free.**

Comment: Seems like you also posted this on English Language and Usage: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/532623/but-except-than-infinitive-with-to-or-without-to

Comment: This is a better place to ask such questions.  Please don't just say "grammar book" but cite it properly and quote it properly.

Comment: @James K, Okay. Thank you.

Comment: @James K, the question has been edited.

Answer (score 2):

The "but" is a red herring; it is distracting you from the actual grammar pattern

Consider these example

> We want be free.
>   We want to be free.

I hope you agree that "want" requires a "to-infinitive"

If I insert an adverb phrase

> We want nothing but to be free

I still need a "to-infinitive".

On the other hand:

> I did cry.
>   I did to cry.

I hope you recognise that "did" uses the "bare infinitive".  Adding an adverb "nothing but" doesn't change that

> I did nothing but cry.

Comment: thank you very much for your valuable opinion. Would you please clarify : "He did nothing but cry" or "He did nothing but to cry" ?

Comment: Would you say "I did cry" or "I did to cry"?

Comment: if "He did nothing but cry" means "He did nothing but he did cry", then 'but' seems to act as a conjunction here ; but I think in the phrase "nothing but" 'but' is a preposition!